# paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Expecting packet from (31,), got 94

Tags: python, paramiko, pysftp

When I use pysftp-0.2.8 to send   a Large files to my sftp service. it always got the same error：paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Expecting packet from (31,), got 94

The file is about 1.5G , when it transfers at 500M, it break.
code here:

```
import pysftp
upftp=FTP(host=ftp_ip, user=ftp_name, passwd=ftp_passwd, acct=ftp_port, timeout=None)
...

try:
    upftp.storbinary('STOR %s'%obj[2], fp, 8192, self.callpecent)      
except Exception as error:
    fp.close()
    self.endit(upftp, 1, '%s,%s'%(obj[2],error), '%s,%s'%(obj[2],error)
```

)

the error message at here:

```
2015-03-24 09:43:05  DEBUG - Rekeying (hit 32729 packets, 536900100 bytes sent)

2015-03-24 09:43:05  DEBUG - Ciphers agreed: local=aes128-ctr, remote=aes128-ctr
2015-03-24 09:43:05  DEBUG - using kex diffie-hellman-group1-sha1; server key type ssh-rsa; cipher: local aes128-ctr, remote aes128-ctr; mac: local hmac-sha1, remote hmac-sha1; compression: local none, remote none
2015-03-24 09:43:05  ERROR - Exception: Expecting packet from (31,), got 94
2015-03-24 09:43:05  ERROR - Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-03-24 09:43:05  ERROR -   File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.14.0-py3.4.egg\paramiko\transport.py", line 1435, in run
2015-03-24 09:43:05  ERROR -     raise SSHException('Expecting packet from %r, got %d' % (self._expected_packet, ptype))
2015-03-24 09:43:05  ERROR - paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Expecting packet from (31,), got 94
2015-03-24 09:43:05  ERROR - 
2015-03-24 09:43:05  DEBUG - Dropping user packet because connection is dead.
2015-03-24 09:43:05  DEBUG - [chan 1] close(b'd40b000000000000')
2015-03-24 09:43:05  INFO - [chan 1] sftp session closed.
```

Thank you for your answer !

Comment: Just ran into this. Found anything to make it work?

Comment: @Matti - In case you haven't figured it out yet - I posted an answer below that might help.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue - turns out it's kind of a known thing with Paramiko. I found the solution on their GitHub at https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/175#issuecomment-24125451. [This one](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/151) was also sort of similar.

The other answer pointed at what was happening but didn't give much to work with. For me, the fix boiled down to something like...

```
self.ssh_client.connect(...)

# -- the important lines
transport = self.ssh_client.get_transport()
transport.default_window_size = 2147483647
transport.packetizer.REKEY_BYTES = pow(2, 40)
transport.packetizer.REKEY_PACKETS = pow(2, 40)
# ---

self.sftp_client = self.ssh_client.open_sftp()
print(self.sft_client.get_channel().in_window_size)
print(sftp_connection.get_channel().in_max_packet_size)

# Output

2147483647
32768
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll be saving this snippet for future. In my case I ended up switching to the system's sftp which I am calling now via the Pexpect package. This way I am seeing much better throughput also.

Answer (score -1):

I find somethings may be useful :)

```
in the paramiko/packet.py

REKEY_PACKETS = pow(2, 29)
REKEY_BYTES = pow(2, 29)

REKEY_PACKETS_OVERFLOW_MAX = pow(2, 29)     # Allow receiving this many packets after a re-key request before terminating
REKEY_BYTES_OVERFLOW_MAX = pow(2, 29)       # Allow receiving this many bytes after a re-key request before terminating
```

and

```
    def _trigger_rekey(self):
    # outside code should check for this flag
    self.__need_rekey = True
```

when it use the re-key ,it goes wrong.